# Output calls to clang when running a build.ninja file

Tags: ninja

How does one view the actual compiler calls (calls to the clang compiler in my case) that ninja generates when processing a `build.ninja` file?

Currently, I just get a bunch of summaries like this:

```
[1/47] Building C object CMakeFiles/proj.dir/home/me/projects/proj/src/native_src.c.o
```

Whereas I would like to see the actual clang command line call for each source file compile.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
ninja -v
```

In my particular use case I am building a native library for an android project, in which case android studio installs ninja to a directory which isn't on the `PATH`, i.e.

```
~/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/ninja -v
```

Running ninja with this option outputs all the clang compiler calls so you can check they are as you expect

source -> https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_extra_tools