# How to get the complete verbose of build commands

Tags: cmake, compilation, ninja

I am using cmake with `Ninja` generator to build my code.

Cmake configure command:-

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCUTLASS_NVCC_ARCHS=80 -DCUTLASS_INSTALL_TESTS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/buildbot-worker/worker/build-tools-main/cutlass/install -DCMAKE_TEST_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/test/work-main/test/install -Wno-dev /home/test/work-main/test
```

Build command:-

```
cmake --build . --target install -v
```

From the logs i could see the info in vague. Which does not help me to debug the issue. It just shows the files name it builds as follows:-

```
[2004/2012] Building CUDA object test/unit/gemm/device/CMakeFiles/cutlass_test_unit_gemm_device_blas3.dir/symm_tf32t_f32t_tensor_op_f32_ls_sm80.cu.o
[2005/2012] Building CUDA object test/unit/epilogue/threadblock/CMakeFiles/cutlass_test_unit_epilogue_threadblock.dir/epilogue_tensor_op.cu.o
```

I am looking for complete verbose details like complete build command that runs to create obj file. Is there is way to log that info via passing some cmake/Ninja flags?

Comment: What is wrong in running `ninja -v` when you build your project? See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681899/output-calls-to-clang-when-running-a-build-ninja-file).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, we are not directly invoking ninja to run the build. Instead we are running cmake command `cmake --build . --target install -- -j 32 -v` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `-v` to ninja, not to CMake. CMake will pass all options following `--` directly to the build-tool, so you need to use

```
cmake --build . --target install -- -v
```

Comment: Actually, this is my build command : `cmake --build . --target install -- -j 32 -v` ,Do we need to explicitly pass `--` for each option that we pass ? i.e. `-- -j 32 -- -v` ?

Comment: When i try to run this command `cmake --build . --target install -- -j 32 -- -v` , i get the error :- `ninja: error: unknown target '-v', did you mean 'all'?`

Comment: @vam No you need to pass `--` only once, everything following it will be passed directly to ninja.

Comment: I am running the build in serial mode `cmake --build . --target install -- -j 1 -v` , When i inspect the log i could see the lines `[182/ 97%]Building CXX object lib\TableGen\CMakeFiles\LLVMTableGen.dir\TGParser.cpp.obj` But the actual build command is showing few lines above the line `[182/ 97%]Building ....` . I was expecting that build command has to be shown just immediately after line `[182/ 97%]Building ...` There are duplicate files that gets built in different folders, And It makes hard to debug on which folder this .obj file was built.